# IntelliJ Idea Not showing GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

For some reason my GUI is no longer showing up on the .form file, instead it is all the hard code for it like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/" version="1" bind-to-class="emroGUI">
  <grid id="27dc6" binding="mainPanel" layout-manager="GridLayoutManager" row-count="11" column-count="7" same-size-horizontally="false" same-size-vertically="false" hgap="-1" vgap="-1">
    <margin top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0"/>
    <constraints>
      <xy x="20" y="20" width="742" height="400"/>
    </constraints>
    <properties/>
    <border type="none"/>
```

etc. 
When I originally made the GUI I did it via 'drag and drop' and I saw the actual GUI form. How do I get the actual form back?

Answer (score 0):

your XML content malformed now and I think you are missing following ending tags:

```
 </grid> </form>
```

accurate structure is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/" version="1" bind-to-class="emroGUI">
    <grid id="27dc6" binding="mainPanel" layout-manager="GridLayoutManager" row-count="11" column-count="7" same-size-horizontally="false" same-size-vertically="false" hgap="-1" vgap="-1">
        <margin top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0"/>
        <constraints>
            <xy x="20" y="20" width="742" height="400"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties/>
        <border type="none"/>
    </grid>
</form>
```